# Netlify support of API for APP in nextjs 13

Tags: next.js, netlify

I have an app with a small API built using [API route of nextjs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-handlers#revalidating-cached-data)

Everything works ok locally, I've created a health route to check and even that is not working :

`app/api/health` :

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

export async function GET() {
  return NextResponse.json(
    {
      message: 'Server up',
    },
    {
      status: 200,
    }
  );
}
```

[image]

Using Insomnia locally :
[image]

WHen I deploy on Netlify, basic nextjs deployment, website works ok, but API route not.

`next.config.js`

```js
const withBundleAnalyzer = require('@next/bundle-analyzer')({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === 'true',
});

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  reactStrictMode: false,
  eslint: {
    ignoreDuringBuilds: true,
  },
  experimental: {
    optimizePackageImports: ['@mantine/core', '@mantine/hooks'],
  },
  target: 'server',
});
```

Response from Insomnia Error 502 :

```json
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
    "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'styled-jsx/style'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js\n- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js\n- /var/task/.netlify/functions-internal/___netlify-handler/___netlify-handler.js\n- /var/task/___netlify-handler.js\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "trace": [
        "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'styled-jsx/style'",
        "Require stack:",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js",
        "- /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js",
        "- /var/task/.netlify/functions-internal/___netlify-handler/___netlify-handler.js",
        "- /var/task/___netlify-handler.js",
        "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
        "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
        "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
        "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
        "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
    ]
}
```

I have no idea why it generate this error

If someone has deploy API using netlify and next13 app architecture, I'm really interested!